# Error when trying to build my Plutus project

Tags: plutus, haskell, cabal, development, ghc

I am getting the following error after trying to execute `cabal build`:

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: cardano-crypto-class (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0.0.1/installed-iw7NtuXmRKLDXiVT5sxh
(constraint from user target requires ==2.0.0)
[__0] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0 (conflict: pkg-config package
libsodium-any, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: cardano-crypto-class)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: cardano-crypto-class
```

I am using `cabal 3.6.2.0` and `ghc 8.10.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `libsodium` :

```
[__0] rejecting: cardano-crypto-class-2.0.0 (conflict: pkg-config package
libsodium-any, not found in the pkg-config database)
```

The way I get around this is `sudo apt install libsodium-dev` and then create a top level file `cabal.project.local` containing:

```
package cardano-crypto-praos
  flags: -external-libsodium-vrf
```

Pretty sure this is documented somewhere in the `cardano-node` repository.

Comment: It is documented here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/1.35.5/doc/getting-started/install.md#installing-libsodium

Comment: It is documented, but it no longer works. Builds are failing with the hack in place.

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. What *specifically* is the problem you are seeing. Probably worth asking that as a new question. You need to specify what steps you are taking and what the error is.